# Issue with history.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm working on react Disney+ clone etc and I was trying to do something like: if user isnt authorized then show login page but if authorized then show content. I used **useHistory** for this. And it works for a second, it just starts to download login page (background image is loading, but text of login page is visible) and then it disappears and content page is shown. Url changes for a second too.

App.js

```
function App() {
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/login"> 
              <Login/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/detail/:id"> 
              <Detail/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/"> 
            <Home/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>    
    </div>
  );
}
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react'

import {selectUserName, selectUserPhoto, setUserLogin, setUserSignOut} from '../../features/user/userSlice' ;
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux" ;
import  { auth, provider} from "../../firebase"
import { useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';


const Header = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const userName = useSelector(selectUserName);
    const userPhoto = useSelector(selectUserPhoto);
    
    const history = useHistory();
    
    const signIn = () => {
        auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then((result) => {
            let user = result.user;
            dispatch(setUserLogin({
                name: user.displayName,
                email: user.email,
                photo: user.photoURL
            }))
            history.push('/');
        })
    }
    const signOut = () => {
        auth.signOut()
        .then(()  => {
            
            dispatch(setUserSignOut());    
            history.push('/login');           
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your issue you can handle Routes in a different way. So you have routes which can only shown during unauthorised situation and some routes only shown for authorised user. For that you can have following implementation.

First you can create **ProtectedRoute** function.

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...restOfProps }) {
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated");
  console.log("this", isAuthenticated);

  return (
    <Route
      {...restOfProps}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
    />
  );
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

And then you can use this function in your main App where you will declare your routes with component.

```
import ProtectedRoute from "./component/ProtectedRoute";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <ProtectedRoute path="/protected" component={ProtectedComponent} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```